# HTML jquery onclick event not working on dynamically-created links on Android phones only

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, onclick, google-chrome-devtools

I am having an issue where dynamically-created links are working on all devices I have tested (in all desktop browsers, on my iPhone, on my iPad, and on my Samsung Galaxy Tablets Chrome Browser), but will not work when clicked on Android phones (I've tested on three Android phones running Chrome, sorry don't have the Chrome versions, but one phone is really new and the others are 1-2 years old at most).

I am dynamically-creating the links to add items to a cart (inside of a larger dynamically-created entity) in a loop.

The link in question is constructed basically like this:

```
var itemHTML = "";
...
itemHtml += '<a href="'+gAddLink+'" class="add2Cartlink">...</a><span>\n'
...
```

Where gAddLink is just a standard URL. I am then inserting that itemHTML (in addition to other HTML) onto the page dynamically using document.write().

Since this is being dynamically created on page load (for reasons out of scope for this question, but it is a necessity), I know I have to have a click handler set up as so:

```
$('.elementToInsertTo').on('click', '.add2CartLink', function() { ... });
```

Where '.elementToInsertTo' is the parent element that is NOT dynamically created, and is present on the page at page load. There are multiple of these parents, hence why I can't use an element ID. Don't think it makes a difference though.

Again, I can confirm that the function call in this click listener works everywhere except Android phones (as far as I can tell). Any idea why this may be? I've read StackOverflow pages all day, but nothing seems related to this. I've read a bunch about JS closures (which may still be the issue) and the like, but none of that seems to be relevant since the link click listener is working on most all devices I have tested on (even the Android tablet's Chrome browser, which is the part that really is confusing to me).

If you happen to have seen this issue before or have any idea why this may be happening, please write it out before reading the next part, so as not to confuse or bias you.

Ok, now to the part that is even more mind-boggling, though I hope this only helps figure this out and doesn't confuse the situation.. I connected one of the phones to my computer with a USB and did some remote debugging using Chrome developer tools as described here (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging). I could confirm there that the click listeners were not working (they weren't being triggered)... (and now here comes the crazy part) *UNTIL* I did some element inspection on the link (i.e. the link was highlighted on my phone as I was inspecting the DOM-element in my browser, again using Chrome dev tools) and then clicked the link. This made it so that the click listener worked!  What?? To debug further, if I inspected any of the DOM elements on the page and clicked the link, the click listener worked. If I changed tabs away from the dev tools tab, or simply stopped inspecting the DOM elements in Chrome Dev tools, the link click listener no longer worked. I really don't know what to make of this, but I'm hoping this part of information narrows down what may be going on with the Android phones and the click listeners.

Happy to try to provide any other info I can, though I am without the Android phone for testing at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried other events like `vclick` or `tap`?

Comment: I did not try those. This site is using RWD, so I was trying not to use jQuery Mobile if possible, just to avoid using any more libraries than I need. I was looking at other stuff on Stackoverflow last night and found something about touchstart, and how you could try either with something like this: `var clickEventType=((document.ontouchstart!==null)?'click':'touchstart');
    $(theElem).on(clickEventType... ` but that didn't seem to work correctly overall.

Comment: you can build custom jQM, include **events** only and try. http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Comment: I got the jQuery Mobile lib and start using tap. Still works everywhere, except Chrome on Android. Also found another twist to this.. I got Firefox on the same Android phone, and the clicks/taps work there.

Answer (score 0):

Tap was still needed (thanks for both suggestions), but the issue was with a 3rd party JS library stopPropogation() call. Apparently this only happened on Android phones, but regardless, after removing the line, the click (on computers) and tap (on mobile) now works everywhere. Thanks!

Comment: i am having same issue,onclick not working onandroid tablet . how did you solve this problem?